# Shopify collections filter, tags in URL

Tags: shopify, liquid

I'm designing a set of collection filters for my Shopify theme, using clickable product tags. Each tag will be passed to URL. From what I see people use three ways of passing/reading parameters:

`/collections/frontpage?constraint=tag`

`/collections/frontpage?f=tag`

`/collections/frontpage/tag+tag`

What would generally be the best/most recommended way?

Answer (score 0):

The last one is the best/most recommended way

```
/collections/frontpage/tag+tag
```

Comment: hi, can you point me to a resource that explains why this is the best/most recommended way? I just started shopify development and I still don't know the difference (if any) of the first and third example.